# No output when reading file

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm using Akka FileIO to read a file line by line as follows:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("MySys")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("/foo/1.csv")).via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String)).runForeach(println)
    system.terminate()
  }
```

But when I run this, I see no output on the console. The file path is correct and there are contents in the file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You terminate AkkaSystem before it has opportunity to process your file.

Do something like this

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("/foo/1.csv"))
  .via {
    Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String)
  }
  .runForeach(println)
  .onComplete{ _ =>
    system.terminate()
  }

Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: Still doesn't print anything to the console.

Comment: Then I suspect it can't find your file. I  just tested this code on random text file on my Ubuntu.

Comment: File path is correct because when I use Source(io.Source("/foo/1.csv")) it finds it and processes it.

Comment: So I ran a toy program on an sbt console and it works. But when I run it in Intellij, even passing the full absolute path it does not pick up the file. I did a copy path as well from Intellij just to make sure I did not do any typos in the file path.

Comment: Not sure what could be the issue. I ran it under debugger from IDEA  2016.3 EAP.

Comment: I created a new project and got it to work. The other one must have been corrupted somehow.

Comment: `onComplete` is a future callback which may not be called because program finish next line. It doesn't help to await result of the future.

Comment: in works in sbt console because jvm (and your program) isn't stopped until your exit console and `Future` has enough time to complete.

Comment: @Mika'il What Alexey says is not precisely correct. The app won't stop even if you don't have stream because active threads of dispatcher will prevent app from exiting.

Comment: I have managed to replicate the problem. If I create a resources folder in Intellij and drop my csv file in there, then I cannot read the file. If I place the file in my scala folder for example, it finds it. The resources folder is marked as a resources root but it fails to pick the file up. I looked on the filesystem and the resources folder is there.

Comment: Also if I create a directory under the resources folder so resources/foo and drop the csv file in there, it finds it a processes it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't wait until your `Future` completes and your program finish before. You could fix it:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("MySys")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  val future = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("/foo/1.csv")).via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String)).runForeach(println)

  import scala.concurrent.Await
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
  Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
}
```

Comment: The app won't stop even if he doesn't have stream because active threads of dispatcher will prevent app from exiting.

Comment: When I wrote answer there were no `Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)` in your answer. Also, do you think that my code won't work?

Comment: Your code will work, Alexey. I didn't downvote (and neither did OP). Perhaps somebody didn't like infinite blocking.